# Combine multiple rows and put in HTML table

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I have table `DiaryData` with columns `Timestamp`, `entry`, `snowFalling`, `snowLaying`, `snowDepth`. I'm only interested in `Timestamp` and `snowDepth` columns.

By running this code:

```
<?php
    $inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();   
    if ($inipath)
    {
    echo 'This script (' . basename(__FILE__) . ') is running with php.ini: ' . $inipath;
    } else {
    echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
    }
    
    echo PHP_EOL;
    
    $myDbase = 'sqlite:\CumulusMX\data\diary.db';
    $pdo = new PDO($myDbase);  // connect to db  ('sqlite:'.__DIR__.'/mytest.db');
    
    if($pdo === false) {
        $liteError = sqlite_last_error ($pdo);
        echo ' Error: ' . sqlite_error_string ($liteError);
    }else{
        echo nl2br (("Success, database ") . $myDbase . (" is open \n\n")) . PHP_EOL;
        
    /*SQLite query used to search for the year, month and total snow for the year by month*/
     $result = $pdo->query( 
        "SELECT strftime('%Y', Timestamp) AS year, substr('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', 1 + 3*strftime('%m', Timestamp), -3) AS month,
                    
            CASE WHEN strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '01' THEN SUM(snowDepth) ELSE '0' END AS Jan,
            CASE WHEN strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '02' THEN SUM(snowDepth) ELSE '0' END AS Feb,
            CASE WHEN strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '03' THEN SUM(snowDepth) ELSE '0' END AS Mar,
            CASE WHEN strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '04' THEN SUM(snowDepth) ELSE '0' END AS Apr,
            CASE WHEN strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '05' THEN SUM(snowDepth) ELSE '0' END AS May,
            CASE WHEN strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '06' THEN SUM(snowDepth) ELSE '0' END AS Jun,
            CASE WHEN strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '07' THEN SUM(snowDepth) ELSE '0' END AS Jul,
            CASE WHEN strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '08' THEN SUM(snowDepth) ELSE '0' END AS Aug,
            CASE WHEN strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '09' THEN SUM(snowDepth) ELSE '0' END AS Sep,
            CASE WHEN strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '10' THEN SUM(snowDepth) ELSE '0' END AS Oct,
            CASE WHEN strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '11' THEN SUM(snowDepth) ELSE '0' END AS Nov,
            CASE WHEN strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '12' THEN SUM(snowDepth) ELSE '0' END AS Dec
            
            FROM DiaryData
            GROUP BY year, strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '01', strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '02', strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '03',
                              strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '04', strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '05', strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '06',
                              strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '07', strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '08', strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '09',
                              strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '10', strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '11', strftime('%m', Timestamp) = '12' 
            ORDER BY year");
        }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Jan</th>
                <th>Feb</th>
                <th>Mar</th>
                <th>Apr</th>
                <th>May</th>
                <th>Jun</th>
                <th>Jul</th>
                <th>Aug</th>
                <th>Sep</th>
                <th>Oct</th>
                <th>Nov</th>
                <th>Dec</th>
             </tr>
            </thead>
          <tbody>
<?php
    $i=0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row["year"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Jan"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Feb"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Mar"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Apr"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["May"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Jun"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Jul"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Aug"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Sep"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Oct"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Nov"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Dec"]; ?></td>
              </tr>
<?php
 $i++; 
} ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I get :

```
Year  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec

2021   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   7.5
2022   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   5.25  0    0
2022   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   6.1   0    0    0
```

I would like header structure like :

```
Year  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec

2022   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   6.1  5.25  0    0
2021   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   7.5
```

The above structure will be in a HTML table using PHP. If I `GROUP BY` just year I get a total of `snowDepth` for that whole year under the `Oct` column. I was able to get `snowDepth` for each individual year and it looked like :

```
Year  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec

2022   6.15.25
2021   7.5
```

but I could never get it to pad out the rest of the months so that the data was in its proper column and I lost how I accomplished that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP code looks like this to fetch and prepare data

```
<?php
$inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();   

if ($inipath)
{
    echo 'This script (' . basename(__FILE__) . ') is running with php.ini: ' . $inipath;
} else {
    echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
}
    
echo PHP_EOL;
    
$myDbase = 'sqlite:\CumulusMX\data\diary.db';
$pdo = new PDO($myDbase);  // connect to db  ('sqlite:'.__DIR__.'/mytest.db');

if($pdo === false) {
    $liteError = sqlite_last_error ($pdo);
    echo ' Error: ' . sqlite_error_string ($liteError);
}else{
    echo nl2br (("Success, database ") . $myDbase . (" is open \n\n")) . PHP_EOL;
    $sql = "SELECT Timestamp,  DATE_FORMAT(Timestamp,'%Y') fYear, SUM(snowDepth)fSnowDepth, DATE_FORMAT(Timestamp, '%m')fMonth FROM diarydata d
GROUP BY fYear, fMonth
HAVING fSnowDepth>0 ORDER BY fYear DESC, fMonth";
    /*SQLite query used to search for the year, month and total snow for the year by month*/
    $raw = $pdo->query($sql);
    $result = array();
    while($row = $raw->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){array_push($result['raw'],$row) ;}
}


if(empty($result['raw']) === false){
    $year = '';
    foreach($result['raw'] as $item){
        if($year !== $item['fYear']){
            $result['data']['years'][] = $item['fYear'];    
            $year = $item['fYear'];
        }
    }

    foreach($result['data']['years'] as $key=>$value){
        
        foreach($result['raw'] as $item){
            
            if($value == $item['fYear']){
                
                for($i = 0; $i <= 11; $i++){

                    if($i+1 == $item['fMonth']){

                        $result['data'][$value][$i] = array('fYear' =>$value, 'fMonth' => $months_list[$item['fMonth']-1], 'fSnowDepth' => $item['fSnowDepth']);

                    }elseif(empty($result['data'][$value][$i])){

                        $result['data'][$value][$i] = array('fYear' => $value, 'fMonth' => $months_list[$i], 'fSnowDepth' => '0');
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
unset($result['data']['years']);
?>
```

and then here goes the html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>combine-multiple-rows-and-put-in-html-table</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered" border="2"; cellpadding="5">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Jan</th>
                <th>Feb</th>
                <th>Mar</th>
                <th>Apr</th>
                <th>May</th>
                <th>Jun</th>
                <th>Jul</th>
                <th>Aug</th>
                <th>Sep</th>
                <th>Oct</th>
                <th>Nov</th>
                <th>Dec</th>
             </tr>
            </thead>
          <tbody>

    <?php 
    foreach($result['data'] as $year => $months) {
    ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $year; ?></td>
                <?php foreach($months as $month){ ?>
                <td><?php echo $month["fSnowDepth"]; ?></td>
                <?php } ?>
              </tr>
    <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's an improvement but it now returns 2021 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7.5 2022 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5.25 0 2022 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6.1 0 0  and doesn't display in my html table. It sits just above it. I'll keep playing with it but so far no luck. Thanks.

Comment: Also from the row count number of values is 11 and you have 12 months check if you edit the for all months, also if you can print_r the $row it will give the idea what it has and how to format it.

Comment: if the data is not huge simple do following

<?php

$result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM DiaryData");

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC){
 $data[] = $row;
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($data,true).'</pre>';

?>

Comment: [0] => Array
        (
            [Timestamp] => 2022-10-05 00:00:00
            [entry] => 
            [snowFalling] => 0
            [snowLying] => 0
            [snowDepth] => 2.25
        )     hope this is what you need @Zubair Ahmd. I was only able to send one array due to size.

Comment: so your DairyData table have five columns named Timestamp, entry, snowFalling, snowLying and snowDepth and we need to sum(snowDepth) foreach month for each year correct?

Comment: Yes to you last comment @Zubair Ahmd.  Here's my actual array:  [0] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2021
            [month] => Dec
            [Jan] => 0
            [Feb] => 0
            [Mar] => 0
            [Apr] => 0
            [May] => 0
            [Jun] => 0
            [Jul] => 0
            [Aug] => 0
            [Sep] => 0
            [Oct] => 0
            [Nov] => 0
            [Dec] => 7.5
        )

Comment: I've done it, it shall perform alot better than your original, you may need to adjust syntax per your db server as I have noticed that you are using sql-lite where I am on mysql should not be big issue for you. me edit the answer

Comment: Thank very much @Zubair Ahmd for your very hard work at helping me. I'm setting up what you provided for SQLITE and most of it coming along. I get this one error that I can't figure out how to correct: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array.  This shows up on the line defining: $result['raw'] = array();.  Any suggestions on how to correct?

Comment: take the new php code from answer

Comment: Got much further than before but hangs up where the push_array line is at and throws this error Uncaught TypeError: array_push(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given. Thought it was asking for something like an isset but that failed. I appreciate your patience with me. Like I said, I'm pretty new to this and I've learned a lot but apparently not enough. :P  @Zumbia Ahmd

Comment: while I'm asking .. I see the word 'data' after $result but not sure where it is initialized. would it be a alias from the sql query or something like that? @Zumbia Ahmd

Comment: $result['data']['years'][] = $item['fYear']; here it initialized and used at the same time, PHP allows to do this.

Comment: $result = array();
    while($row = $raw->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){array_push($result['raw'],$row) ;} 

change $result = array(); to $result['raw'] = array();